# How to execute curl within php loop?

Tags: php, api, loops, curl

I have used postman to execute curl request and get response from the api. Everything is working perfectly. But as soon as I try to execute same curl within a php while loop. It doesn't works at all.

Searched over the internet but did not found any useful information. I would like to know if there is any other way, other than using curl. I also tried **sleep(3)** function from php which sleeps loop for 3 seconds but it didn't helped.

Bottom line **curl is not working in php loop** whereas it works independently.

**Below is my code for reference**

```
        while (($company = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        $company = trim($company);
        if(!empty($company)) {
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.domain.com/services/v3/api/entities?search-term=$company&page-size=10000",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "Authorization: Bearer 78654356gvgfdr43wsdxcfg",
                    "cache-control: no-cache"
                ),
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $response_array = json_decode($response, TRUE);

            $items = $response_array['items'];
            if (!empty($items)) {
                foreach ($items AS $item) {
                    $tt_id = $item['tt_id'];
                    $tt_Name = $item['tt_Name'];
                    $tt_TypeID = $item['tt_TypeID']['id'];                      
                    //save to db                       
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**I tried putting curl init and other setopt before the while loop, but it is not working either.**

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Authorization: Bearer 78654356gvgfdr43wsdxcfg",
        "cache-control: no-cache"
    ));
    while (($company = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        $company = trim($company);
        if(!empty($company)) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, https://api.domain.com/services/v3/api/entities?search-term=$company&page-size=10000);               
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);
            $response_array = json_decode($response, TRUE);             

            $items = $response_array['items'];
            if (!empty($items)) {
                foreach ($items AS $item) {
                    $tt_id = $item['tt_id'];
                    $tt_Name = $item['tt_Name'];
                    $tt_TypeID = $item['tt_TypeID']['id'];                      
                    //save to db
                }
            }
        }
    }
    curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: It's true, you can't use the curl resource in a loop. checkout curl_multi_* functions..

Comment: Thanks, I heard about it, can you suggest a good link. I didn't find any!

Comment: PHP documentation, f.e. curl_multi_init... read the user contributed notes, they contain some examples how to use

Comment: Have you tried running in a for or foreach? Presumably your file is a list of company names line by line. So you could say $companies = file($handle); foreach($companies as $company)... and put your curl code in there. I run curl inside for/foreach loops.

That said, you could vastly speed up processing by using curl_multi, though the code is a bit more complex.

Comment: Hi @David, I am already using while loop. Does it make difference using a for or foreach. Thanks

Comment: @KhanSharukh Personally I shouldn't have thought so. I don't use while loops - the comments above suggest it may be an issue but I can't see why, and have not tested. An alternative would be to wrap the curl into a function and execute it from within the loop.